# DocuSign Resend Envelope to User with Subject correction

Tags: docusignapi

I made custom reminders for my integration that resends the envelope to user. This is work for me:

```
PUT https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/recipients?resend_envelope=true
{
  "signers": [
   {
      "recipientId": "3",
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "email": "janesemail@outlook.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want to send different subject to include "Reminder:"+old subject, how can I modify the emailSubject for specific recipient (which I'm passing to Body), I tried:

```
{
  "signers": [
   {
      "recipientId": "1",
      "name": "Igor",
      "email": "mail@example.com",
      "emailNotification":
         {
           "emailSubject": "ReMiNdEr"
         }
    }
  ]
}
```

But this did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do a `POST` to the recipients endpoint to update the `recipientEmailNotification` for the specific recipient with the `emailSubject` and `emailBody` you wish.

[See reference information](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update)

See [blog post with code examples](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-blog-series-common-api-tasks-change-email-subject-and-body-for-each-recipient/) in six languages (using the various DocuSign SDKs)

Answer (score 0):

So, to resend for recipient envelope with new Subject I need first to determine this property in my POST request, and then I can use PUT with following to update subject, body. If I will not determine this in my 1st POST request, this PUT will not work!

"emailNotification": {
        "emailBody": "NEWSUBJ 44 5",
        "emailSubject": "NEWNEWNEW 44 5"
      },